# Mysql master slave performance

Tags: mysql

Im running a mysql database on a linux server with 24gb ram and im trying to run a performance test of my system.

Now the thing is, when im running it without a slave replication and in particular, without the log bin enabled, the performance are great but as soon as i start enabling the log bin and starting the slave, the performance are sky diving.

My innodb buffer pool is set to 18gb. When i look at the servers during the performance test it seems like the db is not using a lot of its cpu (around 40% most of the times) while the application servers are using most of it for most of the time, for the point of failiure in some cases.

Its worth noting that im not quite a qualified dba but i do have basic understanding about mysql so im sorry in advance if i might need extra guidance here.

Another thing is im currently unable to provide the full my.cnf file but can provide parameter values if you'll need some extra information here.
Thank you very much

Comment: you may need ti tune some replication related parameters such as relay_log_space_limit,max relay log size etc..

Comment: The thing is, in production there are no performance issue, its only in the testing enviorment. However, these parameters are actually not referenced. Can you possibly guide me on how to determine what values should i set them? Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: if so you may compare the production and test env parameters and let us know which are different in both, this way you may have lesser scope to focus. Please share the variables which are different in both env.

Comment: @NawazSohail - I don't see how `relay_log_space_limit` can affect the question.

Comment: Do you have different hardware (between test and production)?  In particular, RAID?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%bin%';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%binlog%';`